# Can Android handle computations in image processing and ttf rendering?

Tags: android, image-processing, fonts, truetype

I am planning to create an Android application that will enable users to draw their own font. One similar app I found, they render the drawings online and sends the ttf file via email. What I want in my study is to render offline and saves the ttf directly into the sd card. Do you think Android can possibly do it? I am worried if it can handle all the computations of the first step which is image processing and handle those parameter requirement in rendering into .ttf (TrueType) format.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why it wouldn't be able to.
If you can't find a API function that can do this, you can always write a small native library (using NDK), and use the FreeType open source library to do the rendering.

If you need an example of character rendering to OpenCV images, look in this short code:
https://github.com/amirgeva/optmatch/blob/master/src/chrmatch/ftfont.cpp